# differentiating HTTP and HTTPS request in Apache

Tags: apache

For a particular file I need to redirect depending on whether it is HTTP or HTTPS and the HTTP method GET . There are few problems like .

I am using setenvif to get to know if the incoming request is HTTP or HTTPS

SetEnvIfNoCase Proxied-SSL .*yes.* IS_HTTPS

How can I use this variable IS_HTTPS in RewriteCond ? and provide a following rewrite/redirect directive to  redirect it to HTTPS .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To check whether request is from **http**  or **https**  you can use `RewriteCond` and `%{HTTPS}`

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}  on
RewriteRule ^particular.php$   /https.php  [L,R=302]
RewriteCond   %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule ^particular.php$   /http.php   [L,R=302]
```

**update**: Since you asked for using environment varietals, here's youre solution:

```
RewriteCond   %{IS_HTTPS}  yes
RewriteRule ^particular.php$   https://%{HTTP_HOST}/https.php  [L,R=302]
RewriteCond   %{IS_HTTPS}  no
RewriteRule ^particular.php$   http://%{HTTP_HOST}/http.php   [L,R=302]
```

Comment: I would like to use the Environment variables instead. Is that possible ?

Comment: I would like to use the Environment variables instead. Is that possible ?    When I use     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on RewriteRule ^(*)/Mypage.xml  - [F] shows forbidden even if the request is for HTTPS . Can you please let me know more abt this ?? Also CAn you please explaing the RewriteRule in your answer.

Comment: I have used the first one in tht case it shows 200k for both https and http if it is "on" and 403 otherwise for both of them . Can you please guide me on this                                  SetEnvIfNoCase Proxied-SSL .*yes.* IS_HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/DiscoveryTree.xml - [F]
</IfModule>

Comment: ok, First you need to replace `yes` with your actual value of your variable, second check the edit!